# Verify user on server after using MSAL2 for login

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I am creating an application where a user logs in using the Microsoft Azure credentials, this login works perfectly on the client side.
However, after logging in, the backend should need to be able to verify that this user is actually able to access the application's content, as not every employee has access to every feature that comes with the app. So in order to validate that, I would like to have my server verify the token the client received to avoid the chances of the user being spoofed.

I have been breaking my head over this for over a week now. I was originally using the microsoft teams library to do the authentication, which worked fine, it allowed the server to do an extra step where it gets the token, but the applications needs to be accessible outside of teams too, and I can't recreate the functionality with MSAL.

**EDIT:** I seem to have been able to use the token received from the MSAL2 login to grab another access token via the server side, this way I can verify the login. I have no clue how I fixed my issue, but I did

Comment: Hi @AlexSNorth, The best way is to implement in your application code to create the log if the user is able to access or rejected from the page and do a post request this log information to your server/database.

Comment: What? I'm sorry but I'm having a hard time understanding on what you mean?

Comment: Openid scope in authentication helps you to get user information(in your app) when the user log in to your application. If you have access to source code of your application then you can add some code to  create logs to check user is actually able to access the application's content and then update it to server.

Comment: None of the answers provided fixed my issue that I am aware of, I am not even quite sure how I fixed it myself, might have been that I was using the wrong ID or something, I am not sure, I just recreated the app at some point and it worked flawlessly. I can't provide the solution myself since I don't know where the problem originated from...

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned you can get user details from OpenID scope in your app authentication. If you have access to source code of your application then you can add some code to create logs to check user is actually able to access the application's content and then update it to server. You can also get [sign in and activity logs information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/concept-sign-ins) in azure.